# How filter data by attribute in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I' m working with firebase. I want to know how retrieve data after filtering consider an attribute of the  data. Think if I want to select the peoples are live in `new york`, then what I do for this. Is there have any query compatible with `select*from table_name where address='yew york'` query.

```
{
{
    name: "ruwan",
    age : 20,
    address: "new york"
},
{
    name: "nuwan",
    age : 23,
    address: "new york"
},
{
    name: "nuwan",
    age : 25,
    address: "melborn"
},
{
    name: "nuwan",
    age : 26,
    address: "dubai"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to use a query in that case, which consists of a combination of ordering and then filtering the data. To get all child nodes with `address` equal to `new york` you'd do:

```
query = ref.orderByChild("address").equalTo("new york")
```

And then attach a listener to the resulting query.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on sorting and filtering data for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) or [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).